# How do you do a match between two tables in a database and then mash the data together into a new table/view?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I have two tables in a database. Lets call them "a" and "b". I have a similar field in both of these tables, of which is not the primary key in either, that can be used to match the data together.

"a" and "b" both contain completely different types of data. "a" has 5 fields, whislt "b" has 8 fields. I am using SQL Server Express with localdb.

How would I got about getting all the fields, from both tables, and doing a match for the similar field in both tables and then putting the connected data into either a new table or view?

Here is some example data:

**table "a"**

```
   ID    ClientID     ClientName     URL                    SoftwareID

    1     12345        Example 1      www.testuri.com        017AAA93o45B
    2     13579        Example 2      www.google.com         029AAA93k32D
    3     29384        Example 3      www.stackoverflow.com  022AAA93j22T
```

**table "b"**

```
ID    ClientID     Username     Email                   Phone            Software

1     29384        User 1      email@email.email        02932 423834     Software 1
2     29384        User 2      email@email.email        02134 234829     Software 2
3     12345        User 3      email@email.email        01293 021924     Software 1
```

The "ClientID" field is the one that is similar between the two.

Comment: add sample data with expected output

Comment: You do this using a join. This is the basis of any query so you need to become very comfortable with this concept. Here is a great representation of the different types. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: This "common field" is not a primary key, but is it guaranteed to be unique for any of the tables? (i.e. a "candidate key") If the answer is no, then you need to decide what you want to do when `n` records from table `a` match with `m` records from `b`, generating in total `n x m` output records.

Comment: You could use a `SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col1, b.col2 INTO myNewTableName FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.myLinkingCol = b.myLinkingCol` to create a new table with the columns you want to keep from table either of the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a new table called `myNewTableName` which contains the data for each clientId from both tables.  The column datatypes of the newly created table will be the same as what those columns were in the original.

```
SELECT [a].[ID] AS [aID]
    , [a].[ClientID]
    , [a].[ClientName]
    , [a].[URL]
    , [a].[SoftwareID]
    , [b].[ID] AS [bID]
    , [b].[Username]
    , [b].[Email]
    , [b].[Phone]
    , [b].[Software]
INTO [myNewTableName]
FROM [a]
    INNER JOIN [b]
        ON [a].[ClientID] = [b].[ClientID]
```

If you don't want a permanent table with this information because it changes often but want to be able to view and query these columns together, then try making a view (this is probably what you want instead of another table with redundant data).

```
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_myViewName] AS
SELECT [a].[ID] AS [aID]
    , [a].[ClientID]
    , [a].[ClientName]
    , [a].[URL]
    , [a].[SoftwareID]
    , [b].[ID] as [bID]
    , [b].[Username]
    , [b].[Email]
    , [b].[Phone]
    , [b].[Software]
FROM [a]
    INNER JOIN [b]
        ON [a].[ClientID] = [b].[ClientID]

GO
```

Then you can select the information from the view just like you would with any normal table but it'll run the query and display you the results.  Query your new View with the following command:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vw_myViewName]
```

Comment: A view would be better though if this was data that changed often and needed to be referenced periodically.

Comment: @BinaryPatrick you're right, this sounds like the perfect place for a view.  I've updated my answer

Comment: @EMUEVIL Thanks for the detailed answer! However, I mistakenly missed out some key information. There can be multiple instances of the "ClientID" field in table "b", but only one instance in table "a". In this case, would this answer still apply?

Comment: @EMUEVIL Sorry, I should have phrased the above a bit better. What I meant to say was that there can be many records in table "b" that share the same ClientID, but for table "a" this field is unique.

Comment: @JohnSmith This just means that the same Client information stored in table "A" will be displayed in each row that has the same ClientID in table B.  The way the JOIN works is basically just matching up the ClientID in both tables and displaying information where they find a match.  I drew up a quick example that might help show how the rows match.  If you have any questions let me know: http://imgur.com/a/OU1p2

Comment: @EMUEVIL Oh, interesting. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!